# How to find next empy cell and place contents of an array

Tags: vba

I am looping through each cell in a column and performing split operation on the text(delimited by ,) for each cell. I have the result in an array.And I am placing it in a range of cells.When ever next cell value is fetched and split operation is carried , new value overwrites the previous result. How can i find the next empty cell and place the array content with out overwriting.

```
Range("A1:A" & UBound(x) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(x)
```

I have texts separated by ,
example A,B,C,D in column E2 
B,M,C... in  E3 and so on till 36000(value may increase)

```
Dim txt As String
Dim x As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim lrow As Double
lrow = Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For j = 1 To lrow

    txt = Sheet1.Range("m2").Offset(j - 1, 0)
    x = Split(txt, ",")
        For i = 0 To UBound(x)
            'Debug.Print x(i)
             Range("A1:A" & UBound(x) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(x) 'How can i change this line to find next empty cell and palce the result in it

         Next i
Next j
```

The above code will loop through each row and split the text. But every time the result is overwritten. How can i find next empty cell and place the result in it?

Comment: It is used only when your satisfied with the answer right?

Comment: you didn't get any for the four answered and not accepted questions? if so, you need to improve quality of your questions.

Comment: Thank you i have rectified my mistake

Comment: back to this question- you need to provide more information. In which way you get `x array`? how is your data organised in the sheet? etc. Please read your question carefully again and ask yourself if you could answer it with the limited information you provided here. We will willingly answer your question if we have all information to give you support. Trust me! :)

Comment: You are searching for an empty cell, but in the sheet you are wondering to place the value, does it keeps the value in random way? What I mean is, A1=xyz, A5=ps,D10=ddm etc. Does your sheet keep value in this way?

Comment: Your question is not being clear, It is making me confuse that you are willing to search empty cells or want to prevent this action "When ever next cell value is fetched and split operation is carried , new value overwrites the previous result."? Please make your question clear.

Comment: Please make me know, Is it useful to you oSheet.Range("A" & i).Value = "xyz"?

Comment: Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A")
IsEmpty(rRng.Value) then **This will help you to find empty cells**

Comment: The cell M2 has long csv ex: m2=abc,Bcd,asad,dfaa m3=asf,sdf,afad and so on. I am able to split m2 and place it in A1. Now when loop fetch m3 it again places it in a1. Only column M2 has csv :)

Comment: Ok then no problem, your selected cell is "A1" and remains same every time. Why don't you change the reference every time. I am sending you an example as an answer please make me know does that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this, This will work for M2=abc,BCD,Xyz,pdt. If M3=zse,ssd,vbd will come it will over write the value A1 to A(j) Value. So update it accordingly.

```
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim M2 As String
    Dim spltStore As Variant

    Public Sub page_load()
    M2="abc,BCD,Xyz,pdt"
    spltStore = Split(M2, ",")
    j = 1
    For i = 0 To UBound(spltStore)
        Sheet1.Range("A" & j).Value = spltStore(i)
        Debug.Print spltStore(i)
        j = j + 1
      Next i
    End Sub
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: If it does not work for you, please make me know. And also try to put more information, if it not works.

Comment: I have edited my answer, please try this one and if any problem occurs, please make me know. And also mention the area where error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
j=1
i=1
Do While IsEmpty(Worksheets("test").Cells(j, i)) = False
 '<do your stuff>   
 j = j + 1
Loop
```

j and i are cell coordinates. This loop will go through all the non-empty cells and stop on an empty one.